# Geocoder search only by city?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-places, rails-geocoder

I'm using Geocoder with google places API on my Ruby on Rails api,

I would like to search locations but only if the city params match my query string.

Eg. Searching for 'X' locations return cities called 'X', with no chance of returning a street or country also called 'X'.

```
Geocoder.search.city('X') #I'm aware that this doesn't work
```

Comment: This question is way too nebulous, it's lacking code to add important context.

Comment: Are you implementing an autocomplete?

Comment: Not at the moment

Comment: Your implementation is not clear.. how do you want to search? Are you searching on client side using the places api or with a help of some gem? What for do you need the Geocoder for? Do you really need the lat and lon?